# file not found exception while fetching RSS feed from news.bitcoin.com in android

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, filenotfoundexception

The link to the RSS feed : https://news.bitcoin.com/feed/

Here is my code thus far :

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RSSDataDownload downloadTask = new RSSDataDownload();
        downloadTask.execute();
    }

    public static class RSSDataDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //DOESN'T WORK, FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION:
            String MY_URL="https://news.bitcoin.com/feed" ;

                try {
                URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                processXML(inputStream);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void processXML(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


           Document XMLdocument= builder.parse(inputStream);

           Element rootElement=XMLdocument.getDocumentElement(); //root element of the XML Document

            Log.d("XML",rootElement.getTagName());

        }
    }


}
```

The above code works for : http://www.bitnewz.net/rss/Feed and http://bitcoin.worldnewsoffice.com/rss/category/1/ and a couple of other RSS feeds, but doesn't work for https://news.bitcoin.com/feed/.

Any special reasons? How to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the problem you are facing but https://news.bitcoin.com/feed/ work for me by using this library.

You can get the idea from **RSS-Parser** library:
https://github.com/prof18/RSS-Parser

Comment: Thank you for the link!
And an interesting thing happened.

I used the idea of the given library and when i logged the result, I got the HTML for a webpage containing a captcha, and not the actual page itself. Any reason why this happened?

Comment: Just checked, it was because of too much scraping that i got that. Emulator also uses our Wifi and as a result fetched that captcha page.

What i did was I connected my pc to another wifi and it started working normally. 

Thanks a ton for your help! If you wouldn't have suggested that library, I would have never understood the actual reason.